# Would the "blue fire" actually hurt Daenerys or her dragons?

Tags: game-of-thrones

From season 7 and 8, it looks like the substance that the Night King's dragon breathes is blue fire.

And, if the "blue fire" were to of touched Daenerys (or her dragons), would it cause damage?

Comment: I don't think we've ever seen any evidence of what blue fire (or ice flame?) does to anything, except castle walls. That and everyone does their best to avoid it, resulting in this lack of evidence.

Comment: Related on Movies: [What is the extent of damage that Viserion's blue fire can cause?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/99889/63559)

Comment: They tried their best to get away, so one could assume...

Comment: The blue fire could burn her clothes off. She would die of frost bite and exposure during winter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The blue fire that Vicerion breathes can melt the Wall and destroy the walls of Winterfell. As far as I know the closest we get to it touching Dany or one of the other dragons is when the Night King surprises them above the clouds. However, we never see it actually hit them. The closest we get it the following:

[image: Vicerion attacks Dany and Drogon]

I would speculate though that the fire would harm Jon and probably turn him into a pile of nothingness like Drogon's fire did to the Tarlys and Lannisters in "The Spoils of War".

Dany is then a special case because whilst the pyre event to birth the dragons was meant to be a one time thing, the show extended it to just a characteristic of Dany so she might be fire proof to it. However, we don't know and dragon fire is something more than normal fire.

Drogon and Rhaegal probably have a deeper protection if not complete immunity to it as they breathe fire themselves and being harmed by what you create wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: *Being harmed by what you create wouldn't make much sense* - you have hydrochloric acid in your stomach, but you wouldn't want to be doused with it. I think it's likely that dragons are more resistant to fire than other animals, but it certainly isn't unthinkable for them to be hurt by it.

Answer (score 0):

The inner core of the candle flame is light blue, with a temperature of around 1800 K (1500 °C). That is the hottest part of the flame. The color inside the flame becomes yellow, orange, and finally red. The further you get from the center of the flame, the lower the temperature will be.

Unless the physics of Westeros works differently, which they very well may, it seems the Night King ‘supercharged’ his dragon to blow hotter. Keep in mind that while it is claimed that fire cannot kill a dragon, the fires of the Doom burned hot enough to kill all the Valyrian dragons, so this seems to not be true. 
We’ll also see with Cersei’s scorpions if death can go down a dragons throat, disproving the claim that it only comes out.

Comment: _"Unless the physics of Westeros works differently"_: as far as I know dragons, White Walkers, shadow babies and wights aren't common in our universe.

Comment: Dragon fire is very different from regular fire. It is hot enough to melt stone and turn men to ash where they stand. Color is not a good indicator in this instance.

Comment: `while it is claimed fire cannot kill a dragon`, Clearly stated in _The Blood of the Dragon_ and _TWOIAF_ (Not sure about TWOIAF) that while a Dragon's scales are _mostly_ impervious to fire, they aren't completely fireproof, Dragons can and have burnt each other. Also, you don't need to wait for Cersei's Scorpions, Rhoynar shot down Meraxes and Queen Rhaenys that way. Also see Battle of the Gullet and Storming of Dragonpit.

Comment: E: Fire and Blood, not Blood of the Dragon. Can't brain today sorry